# Ordenar alfabéticamente palabras de un txt

Tags: c, archivo, algoritmos, ordenamiento

El programa debería coger las palabras de un documento de texto y ordenarlas alfabéticamente para posteriormente guardarlas en el documento de texto.

Utilizo el método de burbuja para ordenarlas alfabéticamente pero no encuentro el error.

Compila y me muestra el documento que muestra "printf("%s", txt);" pero una vez muestra lo que contiene el txt la consola colapsa, al pasar el modo debug entra en el for para aplicar el metodo de la burbuja y aparece el mensaje de "segmentation fault"

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main(){
   int i,j,count;
   char str[25][25],temp[25];
   int txt[200]; // máximo 199 caracteres

    FILE *flujoB = fopen("hola.txt", "r");
    fgets(txt, 200, flujoB);
    printf("%s", txt);
   for(i=0;i<strlen(txt);i++)
      while (fgets(txt, MAXCHAR, flujoB) != NULL)
        printf("%s", txt);


   for(i=0;i<=strlen(txt);i++)
      for(j=i+1;j<=strlen(txt);j++){
         if(strcmp(txt[i],txt[j])>0){
            strcpy(temp,txt[i]);
            strcpy(txt[i],txt[j]);
            strcpy(txt[j],temp);
         }
      }

   printf("Order of Sorted Strings:");
   fprintf(flujoB, "\n");
   for(i=0;i<=count;i++){
    puts(txt[i]);
    fprintf(flujoB,"%s ",txt);
   }
   fclose(flujoB);

   return 0;
}
```

Enlace al [algoritmo](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/02/c-program-to-sort-set-of-strings-in-alphabetical-order/)

Comment: Que errot te lanza???

Comment: He intentado aclarar lo que sucede, gracias.

Comment: Lo encontraste? Si es así, podrías contestarte a ti mismo con la solución o citar el lugar donde la encontraste. Gracias.

Comment: Tu programa ni siquiera compila: la instrucción: `strcmp(txt[i],txt[j])` no es válida ¿Seguro que lo que has puesto es el código que estás compilando? [La función `strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) recibe dos punteros a carácter (`const char *`) ¡pero tú le pasas dos enteros (`int`)! ya que la formación `txt` es de doscientos enteros: `int txt[200];`